# MailKit: How to check if a sent mail has been added to the "Sent" folder?

Tags: mailkit

When I send an email using MailKit, I need to ensure that the email is added to the Sent folder.

Some email servers, like Gmail and Outlook, seems to automatically add the email to the Sent folder. In other cases, I manually locate the Sent folder and add the email.

Currently, I have hard-coded the server to skip the Sent folder addition step if the client is using Gmail or Outlook, but that is obviously a very hacky solution.

Is there a way to check whether a sent email has already been added to the Sent folder, or if I need to do it myself?

Answer (score 0):

You could check the Sent folder for a message that has the same Message-Id header:

```
var uids = sent.Search (SearchQuery.HeaderContains ("Message-ID", message.MessageId));
if (uids.Count == 1) {
    // looks like the message was added
}
```